# I don't want to cancel HTTP request if my request query params are different in SwitchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am using the SwitchMap RXJS operator in my Angular application to cancel the previous requests but it is canceling requests if the query parameters are different.

How we can prevent to cancel previous duplicate request if the request parameters are different?

```
  @Effect()
  loadWeeklyForecastForLongRange$: Observable<LoadWeekForecastForLongRange | Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LoadWeekForecastActions.LOAD_WEEK_FORECAST_FOR_LONG_RANGE),
    switchMap((action: LoadWeekForecastForLongRange) => {
      const url = this.getRequestURLForLongRange(action.payload);
      return this.http.get<APIResponse<WeeklyForecastResponse>>(url)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            }
          }),
          catchError((error) => {
            return handleErrorForTimePeriod(error, LoadWeekForecastForLongRangeFailed, {});
          })
        );
    })
  );
```

Comment: put `distinctUntilChanged` operator with a condition before the `switchMap`

Comment: can you please clarify, you are calling that action again with other payload and previous request cancel?

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` RxJS operator maintains only one inner subscription, and will always cancel in-flight network requests irrespective of the url.

You can use `mergeMap` instead of switchMap, as it can have more than one active inner subscription. But, then it **will not cancel** any inner subscription.

Using `distinctUntilChanged` with either switchMap or mergeMap won't help.
While using it with switchMap, if the query params are different, the control will anyways reach inside switchMap block and previous inner subscription will be cancelled.
And since it maintains the previous state, if we dispatch an action anytime later(i.e when we don't have any in-flight request) which results in same query param as previous action, the HTTP request won't be triggered. *[If this is not an issue with your use case, then you can use it with mergeMap]*

We can also write our own logic of handling the subscriptions and unsubscribing them manually, but using above mentioned operators should suffice in most of the use cases.

Comment: @Ketan Navadiya If neither of the approaches are suitable for your use case, then can you please provide some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Since ngrx's Effects are classes, they can have internal state, so you could try something like this:

```
previousUrl = '';
currentUrl = '';
@Effect()
loadWeeklyForecastForLongRange$: Observable<LoadWeekForecastForLongRange | Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(LoadWeekForecastActions.LOAD_WEEK_FORECAST_FOR_LONG_RANGE),
  tap((action: LoadWeekForecastForLongRange) => this.currentUrl = this.getRequestURLForLongRange(action.payload)),
  concatMap((action: LoadWeekForecastForLongRange) => iif(
    () => this.previousUrl === this.currentUrl,
    EMPTY,
    switchMap((action: LoadWeekForecastForLongRange) => {
      this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
      return this.http.get<APIResponse<WeeklyForecastResponse>>(url)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            }
          }),
          catchError((error) => {
            return handleErrorForTimePeriod(error, LoadWeekForecastForLongRangeFailed, {});
          })
        );
    })
  ))
);
```

Here you use concatMap with the [iif()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) observable to start a new observable if the url is different or start an [empty](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) observable if not